# Add android project classes to Android Studio project

Tags: java, android, git, github, android-studio

Seasoned iOS developer, new Android developer here..

I saw this java class on git hub that I wanted to use. 
https://github.com/CardinalNow/Android-CircleProgressIndicator
My question is very simple yet I could not find help on it anywhere (perhaps a lack of phrasing on my part), but how do i get the circular progress class into my Android Studio project without iterating through the zip download, cutting out the relavent xml, pasting it in my project, copying the java classes, inserting them into my project and changing all the package names.  I figured theres got to be an easier way.

Sorry if this questions has been asked, thanks in advance!

Comment: In this case you have to copy the files in the app module (java and res).
Good alternatives are https://github.com/jpardogo/GoogleProgressBar or https://github.com/castorflex/SmoothProgressBar or

Answer (score 0):

If it's about that one class, just download it, copy the file with ctrl+v and paste it into some folder within your project either within the IDE / Android Studio or via your OS's file manager.

If you need the whole project to be imported, import it as a module via File-> Import module and link to it from your project in your build.gradle, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio).